# What's attribute of password in ActiveDirectory(cn=nameuser)

Tags: active-directory, ldap

If attribute of username is sAMAccountname, for password is ...
I don't found one look like that.

I want to authenticate on login page(browser).
ps.I'm a newbie explain to me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no attribute containing the password.

AD authentication for a web site is possible, but it depends on the language you are using.

Comment: Thanks for answer :)